# rs.update fails on Win Server 2016 - Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle]General error

Tags: windows, oracle, server

I've moved a legacy Classic asp app to Windows server 2016
in large part to resolve TLS 1.0 browser issues. The website works just like it should except for one problem. Updating a DB record fails.

I've set up syswow64 DNS and used a 32 bit Oracle 11g express install on the webserver to talk with the Oracle 11g standard DB. Everything seems to be fine with the application except when updating a sequence table. The code worked fine previously on windows server 2008.

```
rs.open sql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText
If CheckNativeError(cn, SQL, Current_Sub_name) then
fGet_Next_SEQ_ID = ""
exit function
END IF

Opening and reading the recorset works and now need to update the 
rs("NEXT_SEQ") = NEXT_SEQ   (next seq = 222250)
rs.Update
```

Receives the following error.
**Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle]General error**

I'm thinking it is unable to update possibly by a driver issue involving a TLS 1.2 issue but I cannot find the answer why or what to do about it.  Other settings for the website are correct, enable 32-bit code.. app pool, etc.

32 bit Driver used:  Microsoft ODBC for Oracle

Comment: My guess is this is Microsoft not playing nice with Oracle.

Comment: Oracle XE driver works with the same code.  I will need to assume the Microsoft driver can't be used, test everything with the Oracle driver.  Oracle drivers in the past would have problems with some code so we stuck with the Microsoft driver for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to the Oracle XE driver instead of the Microsoft for Oracle driver fixed the issue.  I've tested all the pages and it works fine.  Looks like the Microsoft 32 bit driver will not be useful any longer with the TLS 1.2